# Flash video seek (like youtube)

Tags: flash, video

I have one problem - I have AS2 player and want to make it seek to any point in video (like youtube) no matter - does that buffered or not.

Now I can only seek only on already buffered video piece

Can anyone help me?

best
Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

You need a web server that supports seeking.  Lighttpd supports it through mod flv streaming, and I am sure there are similar modules for apache and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stream your video over the `rtmp` protocol with a `Red5` : http://red5.org